# How can I filter values/key in dictionary that is greater than the other values using Python?

Tags: python

The worksheet that I am practicing right now requires me to print an employee for dismissal which I did.
this is the instruction:
A database of employees in the IT department is given. If an employee's performance level is less than 50, they are considered a poor performer and are recommended for dismissal.

1. Write a function that identifies poorly performing employees. If one is found, "The employee is recommended for dismissal" is displayed. Then they are removed from the database.
2. Apply the function to the employee base. Then display in a column the names of the remaining employees marked "Effective employees:" in alphabetical order.

So far with the help of others, I came up with this

```
staff = {
    'Joe': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 71
    },
    'Ana': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 65
    },
    'Johnson': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 49
    },
    'Jane': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 53
    }
}
staff_dismissal = sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['performance'])[0]

print('The employee', staff_dismissal[0], 'is recommended for dismissal')
print('Effective employees:')
for emp in staff:
  if emp != staff_dismissal[0]:
    print(emp)
```

Output:

```
The employee Johnson is recommended for dismissal
Effective employees:
Joe
Ana
Jane
```

but the problem is the answer is still not correct as it needs to follow the instruction given,  I can't see any resource that would match what I need, please help, I am new to Python, and doing my best to enhance it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to write code that takes one of the `staff.items` and decides whether the employee is effective? Do you know how to write code that iterates over the `staff.items`? What happened when you tried putting those two steps together?

Comment: that is actually my plan, but i don't know the proper code to iterate it, as you can see in my code, I used the sorted function, but aside from that, I don't know other proper function to sort the value that is greater than the sorted item, please help

Comment: You know how `sorted` works, but aren't familiar with either list comprehensions or the `for` loop? Really?

Comment: i am not familiar yet with other parameters that is link with the sorted, as I said, I just started exploring Python recently which is why I am asking here in the community for help.

Comment: `if staff != staff_dismissal:` is pointless. Why compare a dict to a tuple?

Comment: If you store the result of your call to `sorted` in a variable the first element will be the dismissed staff data and you can iterate over the other elements to output the non-dismissed staff data

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  I edited my question above, improved it somehow, but there are conditions that i didn't met

Comment: @IainShelvington I edited my question above, improved it somehow, but there are conditions that i didn't met

Comment: @blhsing I edited my question above, improved it somehow, but there are conditions that i didn't met

Comment: @Christine You're not making any effort in implementing the condition given in the instructions: "If an employee's performance level is less than 50". Please make such an attempt, and come back with your updated code if it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not take the first item out of sorted staff list. Declare the `staff_dismissal` as follows:

```
staff_dismissal = sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['performance'])
```

As they are sorted in `ascending` order of the performance, fetch the first entry. I actually couldn't understand what you've tried to do through the condition `if staff != staff_dismissal[0]` but, it actually makes no sense. However, you'll get the recommended for dismissal and the rest of the employees by doing as follows:

```
print('The employee', staff_dismissal[0][0], 'is recommended for dismissal')
print('Employee that is okay: ')
for individual in staff_dismissal[1:]:
    print(individual[0])
```

**UPDATE**

According to your requirement, you can filter out and sort the ineligible employees and then pop them from the original list. Then you can sort the remaining list. You can do:

```
staff_dismissal = sorted([x for x in staff.items() if x[1]['performance'] < 50], key=lambda item: item[0])

print('Employees listed for dismissal:')

for employee in staff_dismissal:
    print(employee[0])
    staff.pop(employee[0], None)


staff = sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])


print('Effective employees:')
for emp in staff:
    print(emp[0])
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I understand the if condition that you point out, I changed it already, I used other condition to improve it, thank you again!

Comment: I edited my question above, improved it somehow, but there are conditions that i didn't met

Comment: @Christine updated my answer, hope that meets your requirements

Comment: thank you for your help, got it correct but my workbook that has an autocheck, is not accepting the answer. i need to ask someone from the provider of the workbook on why this happened, but thank you so much for your help, i will update you once I got their feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
staff = {
    'Joe': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 71
    },
    'Ana': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 65
    },
    'Johnson': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 49
    },
    'Jane': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 53
    }
}

failNames = []
passNames = []

for emp in staff:
  if staff.get(emp).get('performance') <= 50:
    failNames.append(emp)
  else:
    passNames.append(emp)

passNames.sort()
failNames.sort()

for emp in failNames:
  print('The employee', emp, 'is recommended for dismissal')

print('Effective Employees:')
for emp in passNames:
  print(emp)
```

We can use a for loop to create two arrays: one for employees due for dismissal, and the good ones. Then we can sort the arrays so that they are in alphabetical order. Finally, we just print them out.

Resulting Output:

```
The employee Johnson is recommended for dismissal
Effective Employees:
Ana
Jane
Joe
```

Comment: thank you for your help! things are actually good right now

Comment: I edited my question above, improved it somehow, but there are conditions that i didn't met

Comment: So the only problem is that you want the effective employees to be printed in alphabetical order? And that you want to report employees below 50 as recommended for dismissal (also in alphabetical order)?

Comment: @Christine I edited my post! Let me know if it answers your question :)

Comment: @annika i already sorted the effective employees in alphabetical, but I don't know how to use a condition to get the dictionary values to compare it into less than 50

Comment: @Christine I'm not sure who annika is, but if you meant to @ me, I accounted for that in my for each loop when I did:  if staff.get(emp).get('performance') <= 50:

Comment: sorry about the @ , got confused. but thank you for your help, got it correct but my workbook that has an autocheck, is not accepting the answer. i need to ask someone from the provider of the workbook on why this happened, but thank you so much for your help, i will update you once I got their feedback.

Comment: @Christine ty for the update, I'm happy I could help :) In the meantime, if you can, would you mind upvoting/accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have done:

- Sort the `staff` dictionary based on the employee name.
- Created two lists -

> `dismissals` to store employees recommended for dismissal

> `effective` to store efficient employees.

- Iterate over the sorted dictionary and find out the employees whose `performance` is less than 50 and put them in `dismissals` list and the rest in `effective` list.
- You can see Both the lists are sorted by employee name.

```
staff = {
    'Joe': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 71
    },
    'Ana': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 65
    },
    'Johnson': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 49
    },
    'Jane': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 53
    },
    'Chris': {
        'position': 'IT',
        'performance': 46
    }
}

staff = dict(sorted(staff.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

dismissals = []
effective = []
for i,v in staff.items():
    if v['performance'] < 50:
        dismissals.append(i)
    else:
        effective.append(i)

print("Recommended for dismissals:")
print(*dismissals,sep = '\n')

print("Effective Employees:")
print(*effective, sep = '\n')
```

```
Recommended for dismissal:
Chris
Johnson

Effective Employees:
Ana
Jane
Joe
```

Comment: hi this is also working, but do you know how to make a function based on the employee's performance level that is less than 50?

Comment: You mean a function that says if an employee performance level is less than 50 ?

Comment: I don't see any need for a function here. This - ```if v['performance'] < 50:``` is fine IMO. Any specific reason to use a function ?

Comment: thanks for the help but got a solution already, thank you for your help!